# Anylogic Fluids: Managing Lots

Tags: anylogic

I am pretty new to AnyLogic.

The process I am trying to replicate is Filling a tank and then emptying it. I want to be able to show that each time the tank is filled it has a variable called its LotNumber, and I want to change the color of the fluid with each changing LotNumber.

I have a variable LotNumber which increments correctly, and I have a variable lotColor (driven by parameters RGB) which also increments correctly.
But Batch Color doesn't change with changing lotColor. Batch Number = lotNumber and Batch Color = lotColor on the fluidSOurce properties tab, and I have tried switching custom batch off and on when the tank is full and then empty as an extra trigger. The initial fill of the tank does use lotColor, but this is kept for all fills, even though lotColor is changing

Thanks in advance for your help as to whether this is even possible.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @wayneOS, I am still getting used to the rules/etiquette of Stackoverflow. As per the link,  "Restart from scratch" finds the issue/sloppiness.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you only have a fluidsource followed by a tank:

In your fluidsource:
custom batch checked
batch=LotNumber
custom color checked
color=lotColor

In your tank's actions:
on full: `fluidSource.set_customBatch(lotNumber);`

That should work

Comment: To explain Felipe's solution, the underlying problem is that the Batch setting on FluidSource is a *static* value only, so setting it to `LotNumber` will only evaluate it once (which is why you're seeing only the first lot's colour). However, you can change it dynamically via the `set_customBatch` method at the appropriate time.

Comment: ...and just a conceptual thing. It makes much more sense to change the batch *from the filling side* (i.e., not in the on-full action of the *receiving* tank) because what lot it is is determined when you start the refill. Plus this also allows you to have mixed batches in the tank if it *wasn't* fully emptied before each refill.